# If file has duplicate name but different date, delete oldest date

Tags: powershell

We have database backups taken that are named like this:

```
[dbname]_[date&time].bak
```

These backups are done automatically via in-house software that no one wants to touch, we now only want 1 backup for each database.

So in a folder there could be for example;

```
testdatabase_2017_01_20.bak
testdatabase_2017_02_01.bak

testdatabase01_2017_01_21.bak
testdatabase01_2017_01_23.bak
```

What I want to do is have a PowerShell script that will identify the match in database names and then proceed to delete the oldest.

So far I have come up with the following

```
$regex =[regex] '\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2}'  
$match = $regex.Match($File)

if ($match.Success)
{
    $startingIndex = $match.Index
    $newString = $File.ToString()

    $dublicates = ,$newString.Substring(0,$startingIndex) + $dublicates
}
```

The output of `$dublicates` would be in our example

```
testdatabase_
testdatabase_
testdatabase01_
testdatabase01_
```

What I'm not stuck on is how to say, as there is a match in `$dublicates` find which one is oldest and delete the actual file.

Comment: Please do not edit an answer into a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Get-ChildItem "c:\temp\" -file | where Name -match "._(\d{4})_(\d{2})_(\d{2})" |
    select fullname, @{N="DtFile";E={[DateTime]$_.BaseName.substring($_.BaseName.length -10).replace("_", "-")}},  
            @{N="FileWithoutDate";E={$_.BaseName.substring(0, $_.BaseName.length -11)}} | 
                group FileWithoutDate | 
                        where Count -GT 1 |
                            %{ $_.Group | sort DtFile -Descending | select -first 1} | %{Remove-Item $_.FullName}
```

Comment: Hello, i got this working for what i need, however it turns out the name of the database also contains the time. to i've changed the match to `(._\d{4})_(\d{2})_(\d{2})_(\d{2})_(\d{2})_(\d{2})` but now the delete is not working

Comment: Please ignore the above comment, i have figured it out, will post the solution once complete

Answer (score 2):

This is a standard use case for [`Group-object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object). The general procedure goes like this:

- Collect your input data.
- Group the input data by primary distinguishing feature.
- Select all groups with more than one element.
- Sort each group by secondary distinguishing feature and pick the desired element(s).
- Invoke action on the selected element(s).

In your particular case:

- Enumerate your files.
- Group the files by partial name.
- Select all groups with more than one file.
- Sort each group by date and pick the oldest file.
- Delete the selected files.

```bsh
Get-ChildItem 'C:\backup\folder' -Filter '*.bak' |
  Group-Object { $_.BaseName.Split('_', 2)[0] } |
  Where-Object { $_.Count -gt 1 } |
  ForEach-Object { $_.Group | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | Select-Object -First 1 } |
  Remove-Item -Force
```

If you can't (or don't want to) use the last modification time of the files you can extract the date from the filenames and use that as the sorting attribute:

```
... | Sort-Object { $_.BaseName.Split('_', 2)[1] } | ...
```

Comment: If i understand, he dont want LastWriteTime but date into filename

Comment: and if his file contain an underscore (except date), your code doesnt remove

Comment: The question doesn't suggest that there might be database names with underscores in them. Besides, my answer wasn't intended to be a turnkey solution. It describes the general approach with a gratuitous sample implementation.

Comment: can this be easily modified to remove all but the most recent file? I can run it multiple times to do that, but I'm sure there is better way.

Comment: @Maa421s `sort LastWriteTime | select -First 1` -> `sort LastWriteTime -Desc | select -Skip 1`

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers would it be difficult to display the filenames that are removed (or moved in my case)?

Comment: @Maa421s No, it wouldn't. Please do some reasearch. Questions like that have been asked before on SO. If after your research and attempt to implement your findings you still cant get it to work: post a question of your own describing what you had tried, and how the results were different from what you expected.